# Can a Soap webservice be accessed with the wsdl name ?? and also with the LocationUri?

Tags: spring, web-services

We have a soap-webservice defined through the Spring(spring-ws) and Spring is generating the wsdl through our config. And we have defined the end-point in our code as:

```
wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri(http://xyz:8080/dev/ws/abc);
```

and so the wsdl got generated with the Spring is :

```
http://xyz:8080/dev/ws/def.wsdl
```

and the below is what am seeing as the endpoint in the generated wsdl

```
<soap:address location="http://xyz:8080/dev/ws/abc"/>
```

But our clients are able to access our service with both of the below. 
    http://xyz:8080/dev/ws/def.wsdl    http://xyz:8080/dev/ws/abc.

How does this work or is working. 
Does Spring/tomcat routes or able to route the web-service calls coming in with either the endpoint-path of .wsdl name (def in above) too and also the one with the endpoint (abc in the above) to the end soap web service.

please share any insights, if any have on this. thanks much.

Comment: Not usre I understand what you are looking for. But here goes: A WSDL is only a description of how the web service looks and acts - what methods it exposes, the parameters that are expected for each method, their types, and the responses of each of those methods. But you don't actually call a wsdl. You call the service based on the wsdl. If that makes sense.

Comment: Can you add the complete config and your endpoint class ?